# How can I use xml for Powershell GUI to get version num of PS tool?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have recently started learning to use xml with Powershell to create GUIs. My goal is to create an about box. I use VSCode and Notepad++ (No fancy Visual Studio for me, can't get approved for a license). What I have not yet been able to figure out is how to get the version number of my powershell tool into the xml so it can be displayed. Here are a few code snips

```
<#
File: tool.ps1

Author: Me   Updated: 2021/09/01   Version: 0.1.2
   Change notes ... 
   Blah Blah .

Author: Me   Created: 2021/08/01   Version: 0.1.1
   Basic Script notes for version number

#>
```

We get the file version info from our compile script, which pulls it from the
.ps1 file and inserts it into the executable. The "authorLines" will look like
my comment block above. NOTE: We use Microsoft's PS2Exe with our compiler. The
code block to retrieve version is:

```
$authorLines = get-content $srcFile | Where-Object {$_ -match 'Author'}
      if((Get-ArraySize $authorLines) -gt 1) {
         $fileVersion = ($authorLines[0] -split ' ')[-1]
      } elseif ((Get-ArraySize $authorLines) -eq 1){
         $fileVersion = ($authorLines -split ' ')[-1]
      }else{
         $fileVersion = $null
      }
```

This is the code in my .ps1 to get the file version info from the executable

```
$fileVersion = (Get-Command '.\tool.exe').FileVersionInfo.FileVersion
```

The following is in a separate xml file (necessary for the tools we use.
We cannot have our xml inside the Powershell script!). My xml is longer
with more data, but this is the important part

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Name="about"
Width="400"
Height="550"
Title="About">
<Grid x:Name="Grid"
      Margin="10,10,10,10">
   
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<!-- Begin About Properties -->    
   <Label Grid.Row="0" 
          Grid.Column="0" 
          x:Name="label1" >
   <Run FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Text="Tool Name Here"  /> 
      </Label>
   <Label Grid.Row="1" 
          Grid.Column="0" 
          x:Name="label2" 
         >
   <Run FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Text="Tool Version Number: "  /> 
   </Label>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code to pull the GUI xml (retrieveFile is a powershell module created by my team, it searches a named directory for a named file; all error checking is done in the module):

```
$aboutXaml = retrieveFile -folderPath "F:\powershellGUI" -fileSelect "about.xml"
$global:aboutWindow = New-Object xml
$global:aboutWindow.Load($aboutXaml)
```

So, is there a good way to pull file version info from the tool and get it into the xml? Other than manually typing it - we want to make sure it stays current?. As an example, I am adding a screenshot of the VScode about box. I'm not too worried about most of the other info, just how to get version number in there. Any help is appreciated

[image: VS Code about box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an easily identifiable template string in the base XML and just replace that with the version in the file as a build step. In your XML, change the Text attribute of the XML element to use a replaceable value, such as `{{VERSION_NUMBER}}`:

```xml
<Run FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Text="Tool Version Number: {{VERSION_NUMBER}}" />
```

Then as a build step, replace `{{VERSION_NUMBER}}` with the `$fileVersion` PS2EXE would assign once it runs. Assuming `$xmlPath` is the path to the XML file:

```
( Get-Content -Raw $xmlPath ) -replace '{{VERSION_NUMBER}}', $fileVersion | Out-File $xmlPath -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found a fairly simple way, using my already existing code above (changing label2 name to fileVersionInfo, and loading $aboutBox as the reader).

```
$fvInfo = $aboutBox.FindName("fileVersionInfo")
$fvInfo.Content.Text = $fileVersion
```